# Reading out put of previous command in bat command file

Tags: batch-file

I am very new to batch programming, I am trying to write a batch file  that is a fake virus. I need to obtain the `IP address` from the previous command `IPCONFIG` into the variable `VarIP`.  Can you help me?

My code:

```
echo off

echo Trying to hack your computer

ipconfig

echo Now hacking your IP

ping -t VarIP

echo on

pause
```

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty simple to extract part of the output from any console command by using `find` to eliminate the lines in the output that you do not want, then using the `for` command to extract a portion of the line found by `find`:

```
@echo off

setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

for /f "tokens=2 delims=:" %%i in ('ipconfig ^| find /i "IPv4 Address"') do (set VarIP=%%i&set VarIP=!VarIP: =!)
ping -t !VarIP!

endlocal
```

Hopefully you are just creating a practical joke on a friend and aren't up to anything more nefarious.

Answer (score 0):

Another Version without "Tokens" for NT :

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('ipconfig ^| find /i "IPv4 Address"') do (set VarIP=!%%a%!)
ping -t %VarIP%
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a useful method to get IP info:

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=2,3 delims={,}" %%a in ('"WMIC NICConfig where IPEnabled="True" get IPAddress /value | find "I" "') do echo IPv4 %%~a IPV6 %%~b
pause
```